# Is there any performance reasons to change a function into a static function?

Tags: actionscript, intellij-idea

When developing actionscript/flex in IntelliJ IDEA, there's this IDEA inspection that suggests that so-and-so private function can be turned into a static function.

I've been ignoring it for a while now, but I'm curious as to whether, in actionscript, there's any performance benefit of declaring functions that *can* be static as static.

Coming from a Java background, it seems odd to me for IDEA to be suggesting that a function be made static just because it can... yet such an inspection does not exist in the Java editor.

For example, IDEA would suggest that I make the following static:

```
    private function eventName(attributeName:String):String {
        return attributeName + EVENT_NAME_SUFFIX;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There is actually quite an incentive to do the opposite.

This should not be so - naturally, one would think static functions would be faster - but ActionScript 3 does not behave this way.  Whoever wrote IDEA did not do their research on this, but rather they went with their instincts and with what *should* be true.

Here's one source of information on this subject:

http://blog.controul.com/2009/04/how-slow-is-static-access-in-as3avm2-exactly/